# PHP return nothing if array_column fields are blank

Tags: php, arrays

The below code takes an array, `$array`, and an array key, `$item` and implodes by adding a comma to each item.  How can I alter it so that if the value of the item inside the array is null, then the implode will not add a blank comma.

```
public static function implode($array, $item) 
{
    return implode(',', array_column($array, $item));
}
```

For example:

```
$array = [
    ['eri_number' => ''],
    ['eri_number' => '222']
    ['eri_number' => '']
];
$item = 'eri_number';
$myClass->implode($array, $item);
```

The above code will output;

```
,222,
```

I just want it to output `222` without the other blank values.

Can anyone help?

Comment: [array_filter](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-filter.php)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could filter out the empties using `array_filter()`:

```
return implode(',', array_filter(array_column($array, $item)));
```

Note that this will also filter out `0`, string `0`, `false` and `null`.

Answer (score 0):

Apply [array_filter](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-filter.php) to the array before imploding.

```
public static function implode($array, $item) 
{
    return implode(',', array_filer(array_column($array, $item)));
}
```

You can add a callback function to define what you want to filter out, but since the empty string is falsey, it should work for you right out of the box.